# Changing 2D ArrayList code to 2D array code

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I found this code online and it works well to permute through the given array and return all possible combinations of the numbers given. Does anyone know how to change this code to incorporate a 2D array instead?

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> permute(int[] numbers) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> permutations = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    permutations.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

    for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ) {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> current = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for ( ArrayList<Integer> p : permutations ) {
            for ( int j = 0, n = p.size() + 1; j < n; j++ ) {
                ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(p);
                temp.add(j, numbers[i]);
                current.add(temp);
            }
        }
        permutations = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(current);
    }

    return permutations;
}
```

This is what I have attempted:

```
public static int[][] permute(int[] numbers){
    int[][] permutations = new int[24][4];
    permutations[0] = new int[4];
    for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ) {
        int[][] current = new int[24][4];
        for ( int[] permutation : permutations ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < permutation.length; j++ ) {
                permutation[j] = numbers[i];
                int[] temp = new int[4];
                current[i] = temp;

            }

        }
        permutations = current;
    }
    return permutations;

}
```

However this returns all zeroes. I chose 24 and 4 because that is the size of the 2D array that I need.
Thanks

Comment: Read up on arrays. Show an effort. The best way to get help on Stack Overflow is: write some code, if you cannot get it to work, post what you have along with any error messages and other results you get. For more info, please follow this link: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read.

Comment: I just edited to add my initial attempt. I already had this attempt when I initially posted but I didn't think it would be of much use. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not really that easy. The original code exploits the more dynamic behaviour of `ArrayList`, so a bit of hand coding will be necessary. There are many correct thoughts in your code. I tried to write an explanation of the issues I saw, but it became too long, so I decided to modify your code instead.

The original `temp.add(j, numbers[i]);` is the hardest part to do with arrays since it invloves pushing the elements to the right of position `j` one position to the right. In my version I create a temp array just once in the middle loop and shuffle one element at a time in the innermost loop.

```
public static int[][] permute(int[] numbers) {
    // Follow the original here and create an array of just 1 array of length 0
    int[][] permutations = new int[1][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        // insert numbers[i] into each possible position in each array already in permutations.
        // create array with enough room: when before we had permutations.length arrays, we will now need:
        int[][] current = new int[(permutations[0].length + 1) * permutations.length][];
        int count = 0; // number of new permutations in current
        for (int[] permutation : permutations) {
            // insert numbers[i] into each of the permutation.length + 1 possible positions of permutation.
            // to avoid too much shuffling, create a temp array
            // and use it for all new permutations made from permutation.
            int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(permutation, permutation.length + 1);
            for (int j = permutation.length; j > 0; j--) {
                temp[j] = numbers[i];
                // remember to make a copy of the temp array
                current[count] = temp.clone();
                count++;
                // move element to make room for numbers[i] at next position to the left
                temp[j] = temp[j - 1];
            }
            temp[0] = numbers[i];
            current[count] = temp.clone();
            count++;
        }
        assert count == current.length : "" + count + " != " + current.length;
        permutations = current;
    }
    return permutations;
}
```

My trick with the temp array means I don’t get the permutations in the same order as in the origianl code. If this is a requirement, you may copy `permutation` into `temp` starting at index 1 and shuffle the opposite way in the loop. `System.arraycopy()` may do the initial copying.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a way to make the temp[] array without the use of the copyOf() method from the Arrays class?

Comment: Sure, @Anon. Just do `new int[permutation.length + 1]` and copy the elements into the new array. For the copying you may either use `System.arraycopy()` if you find it acceptable, or copy the elements one by one in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you really need to implement properly the array version of the `ArrayList.add(int,value)` command. Which is to say you do an System.arraycopy() and push all the values after j, down one and then insert the value at j. You currently set the value. But, that overwrites the value of permutation[j], which should actually have been moved to permutations[j+1] already.

So where you do:

```
permutation[j] = numbers[i];
```

It should be:

```
System.arraycopy(permutation,j, permutations, j+1, permutations.length -j);
permutation[j] = numbers[i];
```

As the ArrayList.add(int,value) does that. You basically wrongly implemented it as .set().

Though personally I would scrap the code and go with something to dynamically make those values on the fly. A few more values and you're talking something prohibitive with regard to memory. It isn't hard to find the nth index of a permutation. Even without allocating any memory at all. (though you need a copy of the array if you're going to fiddle with such things without incurring oddities).

```
public static int[] permute(int[] values, long index) {
    int[] returnvalues = Arrays.copyOf(values,values.length);
    if (permutation(returnvalues, index)) return returnvalues;
    else return null;

}
public static boolean permutation(int[] values, long index) {
    return permutation(values, values.length, index);
}

private static boolean permutation(int[] values, int n, long index) {
    if ((index == 0) || (n == 0))  return (index == 0);
    int v = n-(int)(index % n);
    int temp = values[n];
    values[n] = values[v];
    values[v] = temp;
    return permutation(values,n-1,index/n);
}
```